# How do I activate the launcher to deliver Sin's package in Yoku's Island Express?

Tags: yokus-island-express

In order to deliver Sin's package you have to get on a floating island below his house and launch yourself using one of those yellow bumpers, not a flipper. I cannot get the bumper to fire. I've watched a video where someone gets to the platform and sort of pushes against the bumper for a second then suddenly they get launched, but I simply cannot get it to work. Is there a trick to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an idiot. It actually is a flipper, it's just buried so far in the ground it looks like the bumpers. And apparently I hadn't actually tried activating with the triggers. Well anyhow, just hit the right trigger and off you go.